# What does "as" in "response.json() as Hero[]" do?

Tags: angular

Sometimes I can see some codes handle http response like this:

```
f(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get('local.host').map((response: Response) => response.json().data as Hero[]);
}
```

and Hero is

```
export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

what does

```
r.json().data as Hero[]
```

mean?

But as far as I know, now there is no direct function to convert json object to ts object,is the keyword "as" used to convert a json object into custom ts object? if so, can I write

```
var myClass=r.json()  as MyClass;
if(!myClass){
    //error
}
```

to check if the json object can be converted into my custom class?

Comment: It's type casting in TypeScript. Basically you mark the object as type `Hero[]` so you can work on the same object as if it's `Hero[]` (e.g. you can iterate through `Hero` items, find the length of array, etc.). But it doesn't guarantee the actual object has those properties/methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HarryNinh said

> TypeScript 1.6 introduces a new .tsx file extension. This extension does two things: it enables JSX inside of TypeScript files, and it makes the new as operator the default way to cast (removing any ambiguity between JSX expressions and the TypeScript prefix cast operator). For example:

```
var x = <any> foo;
// is equivalent to:
var x = foo as any;
```

Ref: [Typescript 1.6 ChangeLog](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#new-tsx-file-extension-and-as-operator)

Answer (score 3):

### as keyword is casting

```
r.json().data as Hero[]
```

On response from Server . It is expected that List of Object returns from server.
This piece of code is just type casting.

It will convert that list into Hero Object array.
Servers return the value in **json format**